# Python: Problems when iterating over a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have been working on this simple Python program to get familiar with dictionaries. Basically, it works as a database which you can search in. If your entry is in the dictionary key, it brings up the information regarding the entry.

```
Family = {'Jim' : ['cool guy', 'has facial hair'],
          'Ned' : ['hot stuff', ' wears Tees']}

query = input("Look up database on whom? > ")
for (name, info) in Family.items():
    if name in query or name.lower() in query:
        print("{} is {}".format(name, info))
```

This ^ works. However, when I tried to add an ELSE clause, to deal with non-existent entries, I get this.

```
else:
    print ('Value not found!')
```

It prints the Value not found! many times before bringing up the value. If I try to add a 'go back to start' function it doesn't even bring up a registered value. I know this is because it is a loop and iterates over the dict one by one; so like 1)jim is true then 2) ned is false.

How do I improve this code to make it: -able to give an error about a non-existent entry and then restart the program. Thanks.

Comment: is your else indented to be level with the `for` or the `if`? Looks like its the `for`.

Comment: No, it is indented with the `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
Family = {'Jim' : ['cool guy', 'has facial hair'],
          'Ned' : ['hot stuff', ' wears Tees']}

query = input("Look up database on whom? > ")
if query in Family.keys():
    for (name, info) in Family.items():
        if name in query or name.lower() in query:
            print("{} is {}".format(name, info))
else:
    print "Print Something - Not in Family"
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this answer the easiest to understand. I just changed `if query in Family.keys():` to `if query.capitalize() in Family.keys():` to allow for lower case entries

Answer (score 1):

You will need to take care of case insensitivity in your code. Iterate through the list to ensure that the name exists before continuing:

```
Family = {'Jim' : ['cool guy', 'has facial hair'],
          'Ned' : ['hot stuff', ' wears Tees']}

names = [name.lower() for name in Family]
def find(query):
    if query.lower() in names:
        info = [Family[n] for n in Family if n.lower() == query.lower()]
        print('{} is {}'.format(
            query, info
        ))
    else:
        print('{} not found'.format(query))
```

If you try it with the following sample:

```
find('Ned')
find('ned')
find('no ned')
```

You will get the following results:

```
Ned is [['hot stuff', ' wears Tees']]
ned is [['hot stuff', ' wears Tees']]
no ned not found
```